# Remove tablespace info from Materialized View DDL

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, materialized-views

Using the following SQL, the DDL for a given materialized view can be obtained.

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM, 'STORAGE', FALSE);
    DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM, 'TABLESPACE', FALSE);
    DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM, 'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES', FALSE);
END;
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('MATERIALIZED_VIEW', 'OBJECT_NAME', 'SCHEMA_NAME') FROM DUAL;
```

I am having difficulty retrieving the DDL without the tablespace information. The `SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM` directives are actually documented as being specific to tables and indexes (not materialized views). The `STORAGE` one does actually work whereas the `TABLESPACE` and `SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES` ones have no effect. Is there any way to omit the tablespace info from the generated DDL?

Comment: Where are you running the code and what does the output look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the object_type in the calls to SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM to MATERIALIZED_VIEW. In my example below, the tablespace is no mentioned:

```
create materialized view mv
as select * from large_t where rownum < 100;

begin DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM (
              transform_handle => dbms_metadata.session_transform,
              name             => 'TABLESPACE',
              value            => false,
              object_type      => 'MATERIALIZED_VIEW');
end;
/

select dbms_metadata.get_ddl(
           'MATERIALIZED_VIEW',
           'MV',
           user)
         from dual;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "SODONNEL"."MV" ("OWNER", "OBJECT_NAME", "SUBOBJECT_NAME", "OBJECT_ID", "DATA_OBJECT_ID", "OBJECT_TYPE", "CREATED", "LAST_DDL_TIME", "TIMESTAMP", "STATUS", "TEMPORARY", "GENERATED", "SECONDARY", "NAMESPACE", "EDITION_NAME")
  ORGANIZATION HEAP PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  BUILD IMMEDIATE
  USING INDEX 
  REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND
  USING DEFAULT LOCAL ROLLBACK SEGMENT
  USING ENFORCED CONSTRAINTS DISABLE QUERY REWRITE
  AS select * from large_t where rownum < 100
```